# if/else в onclick

Tags: javascript

```js
<div class="price" onclick="$(this).find('.popup_block').css('height',     '660px');">
<span class="name" style="font-size: 12px;">Подробнее</span>
<div class="popup_block" style="height: 660px;">
```

При нажатии на подробнее, блоку добавляется *660px* высота, а когда нажимаю снова на ту же кнопку, то высота на *0* не становится. Решил, что нужно сделать проверку если высота больше *0*, то ставить *0*, а если равна *0*, то ставить *660px*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данный `onclick` добавить проверку?

Comment: было бы неплохо код увидеть

Comment: `<div class="price" onclick="$(this).find('.popup_block').css('height',  $('.popup_block').height() > 0 ? '0' : '600px');">`

Comment: Прятать и показывать можно, меняя свойство display (block|none) или visibility (visible|hidden|inherit). В большинстве случаев предпочтительней установки высоты.

Comment: Тут display по заданию не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="price" onclick="myHandler()">
```

JS:

```
//Ваш обработчик, в нем и пишите if
function myHandler() {
    if($('.popup_block').height() > 0) {
        //do 1
    } else {
        //do 2
    }
}
```

[jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

**P.S.**
Я не являюсь front-end разработчиком, но те разрабы, с кем я общался на эту тему, говорят, что лучше регистрировать обработчики в JS, вот так:

```
$('.price').on('click', function() {
    if($('.popup_block').height() > 0) {
        //do 1
    } else {
        //do 2
    }
});
```

Здесь, второй параметр - это функция, которая будет выполняться при каждом клике на элемент, у которого есть класс `price`, таким образом, Вы единожды регистрируете обработчик для всех блоков с классом.